# ¿Hay alguna manera de comprobar que un fichero se creó correctamente aprovechando el comando mkdir?

Tags: bash

Supongamos el siguiente **código**:

```
function folderExist(){
        # Si no existe el destino, lo creamos
        if [[ ! -d ${PATH}/${ETC} ]]
                then mkdir -p ${PATH}/$ETC
        # Comprobamos si podemos escribir en el destino
        if [[ ! -w ${PATH}/${ETC} ]];
                then exit $ERR
}
```

Quisiera comprobar si, tras verificar que el fichero de **destino no existe y crearlo**, se creó bien el fichero de destino, pero **haciendo uso de mkdir** para no tener que volver a comprobar su existencia con otro condicional igual al primero (podría suceder un error en la ejecución de mkdir que impidiera la creación del destino).

Imagino que mkdir tiene en su implementación alguna funcionalidad que le haga retornar un código de error que yo pueda capturar y lanzar el mío propio (*exit $ERR*) o algo así, ¿no?

Gracias.

**P.D.:** si no me equivoco, no hacen falta las llaves para rodear a las variables en ningún caso, ¿cierto? Es que soy nuevo en Bash :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para comprobar si `mkdir` ha tenido éxito podrias usar su *código de retorno*. Si éste es `0` la operación es correcta. Si es cualquier otro valor entonces hay un *error*. Usando `-p` tambien te devuelve `0` *aunque antes ya existiera*. Por lo tanto:

```
mkdir -p tu_directorio/
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "Error durante la creación de la carpeta"
else
    echo "La carpeta se ha creado correctamente o ya existía"
fi
```

Donde:

- `$?` es la captura del código de retorno del último comando ejecutado, en este caso `mkdir -p`
- `ne` representa **not equal** (no es igual)

En la última línea de su [documentación completa](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/mkdir) dice lo siguiente:

> An exit status of zero indicates success, and a nonzero value
> indicates failure.

Para comprobar despues si un archivo existe ejecuta ésta comprobación:

```
FILE=/ruta/a/tu/archivo.txt
if [[ -f "$FILE" ]]; then
    echo "$FILE existe."
else 
    echo "$FILE no existe."
fi
```

Donde:
`-f ARCHIVO` Devuelve `true` si el ARCHIVO existe y es un archivo regular (no un directorio ni un dispositivo).

Y se puede poner sin corchetes, con corchetes simples o dobles, <s>aunque si quieres **evitar problemas con los espacios en nombres de archivos o carpetas** entonces usa *corchetes dobles* `[[]]`.</s> *(corrección, lo malinterpreté, no es cierto completamente)*

He usado el operador de testeo de archivo `-f` pero hay unos cuantos más que he [encontrado aquí](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-check-if-file-exists/), por si quieres cambiarlo por otro más adecuado en tu caso:

```
-b FILE - True if the FILE exists and is a special block file.
-c FILE - True if the FILE exists and is a special character file.
-d FILE - True if the FILE exists and is a directory.
-e FILE - True if the FILE exists and is a file, regardless of type (node, directory, socket, etc.).
-f FILE - True if the FILE exists and is a regular file (not a directory or device).
-G FILE - True if the FILE exists and has the same group as the user running the command.
-h FILE - True if the FILE exists and is a symbolic link.
-g FILE - True if the FILE exists and has set-group-id (sgid) flag set.
-k FILE - True if the FILE exists and has a sticky bit flag set.
-L FILE - True if the FILE exists and is a symbolic link.
-O FILE - True if the FILE exists and is owned by the user running the command.
-p FILE - True if the FILE exists and is a pipe.
-r FILE - True if the FILE exists and is readable.
-S FILE - True if the FILE exists and is a socket.
-s FILE - True if the FILE exists and has nonzero size.
-u FILE - True if the FILE exists, and set-user-id (suid) flag is set.
-w FILE - True if the FILE exists and is writable.
-x FILE - True if the FILE exists and is executable.
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario el punto y coma después del condicional? En los ejemplos que he leído en Internet no usan el punto y coma nunca

Comment: @SergioDuránVega Si el `then` va a continuación teóricamente es necesario. Si lo pones en la siguiente línea diria que no. Según [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117346/why-do-some-people-put-a-semicolon-after-an-if-condition-in-shell-scripts)  (en inglés) arroja un error de bash si no lo haces bien:  `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'`